# Term for a unorthodox/reverse analogy?

Tags: terminology

Is there a term for a unorthodox/reverse analogy? I saw some posts regarding this but didn't find the answer that i needed. What i mean by unorthodox/reverse analogy is the following.

**Common analogy: He yearned for fame like a man yearning for water.**

but i saw this analogy being made in reverse.

**He yearned for water like an ambitious man yearning for fame.**

Is there a term for this? Also, please forgive me if I'm using any terminology incorrectly. My apologies. Thank you!

Comment: Aren't they both just similes? Perhaps one is more cliched than the other, but I wouldn't call them analogies.

Comment: Is there a term for the less cliched one?

Comment: 'Originality'? I don't think so. Although I can see what you are getting at, I think, unless you can find one in the list of Greek rhetorical devices (which is a possibility), that the answer is 'no'. Why do you want to know?

Comment: Just because. I am reading a lot of literature that has these types of reverse similes. And I just wanted to be able to refer to them another way than just saying, "less-cliched comparisons."

Comment: Off-topic here, sending to the English site.